# How to manage user feedback?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-experience

I am working on an app and would like to allow users to provide feedback, ask questions etc. I'm doing this to improve user experience and allow for an avenue for users to communicate with me. The best way I can think of communicating with users is via email. So I created a two-step form where they first input their email in the first step and then a description of their problem, question, or feedback in the second step. Once they submit the form, an email should be sent to me with the user's email and description. From that point, I would email the user back and address their query.

I have a few questions:

1. Is this the best way to manage user feedback? Is there a better way?
2. I have to use the [mailer package](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) to make this all possible, however, it requires that I provide the password to my email in my code. Aside from having to deal with the problems associated with exposing my password (possibly exploitable by hackers), it seems that I would have to send an email to myself using this package. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you manage a server environment?

Comment: I'm doing everything through firebase

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> dependencies:
>   in_app_review: ^2.0.1
> ```

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_review/in_app_review.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

enum Availability { LOADING, AVAILABLE, UNAVAILABLE }

extension on Availability {
  String stringify() => this.toString().split('.').last;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final InAppReview _inAppReview = InAppReview.instance;
  String _appStoreId = '';
  String _microsoftStoreId = '';
  Availability _availability = Availability.LOADING;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      try {
        final isAvailable = await _inAppReview.isAvailable();

        setState(() {
          _availability = isAvailable && !Platform.isAndroid
              ? Availability.AVAILABLE
              : Availability.UNAVAILABLE;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() => _availability = Availability.UNAVAILABLE);
      }
    });
  }

  void _setAppStoreId(String id) => _appStoreId = id;

  void _setMicrosoftStoreId(String id) => _microsoftStoreId = id;

  Future<void> _requestReview() => _inAppReview.requestReview();

  Future<void> _openStoreListing() => _inAppReview.openStoreListing(
        appStoreId: _appStoreId,
        microsoftStoreId: _microsoftStoreId,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('InAppReview Example')),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('InAppReview status: ${_availability.stringify()}'),
            TextField(
              onChanged: _setAppStoreId,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'App Store ID'),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: _setMicrosoftStoreId,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Microsoft Store ID'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _requestReview,
              child: Text('Request Review'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _openStoreListing,
              child: Text('Open Store Listing'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in point 2, you will have to send yourself an email from your account and this brings vulnerabilities.

In my experience, if you are not using a server environment, you can use an external support service (tickets) and add this via a package or via InAppWebView.

This way you will not have the vulnerability of giving the password to third parties, and you will also be able to receive the comments to your email.

A more sophisticated solution is to create in a server environment all the logic to receive information from the Flutter interface, and start a communication through the medium that you define.

Comment: Do you know any external support service package?

Comment: Package on dart no, but I have used this external service. https://freshdesk.com/